# How to display RGB Texture by OpenGL in Swift?

Tags: opengl-es, swift, ios8, xcode6

I want to display a RGB Texture by OpenGL in Swift,

It was working fine in Objective-C, and I tried to porting the code to Swift Language,

I can not really understand how to pass the values to shader in Swift by custom struct,

anyone can provide a simple tutorial about how to display RGB texture by OpenGL in Swift ?

my shaders:

> **Vertex:**

```
precision highp float;

attribute vec2 positionCoords;
attribute vec2 textureCoords;

uniform mat4 modelViewProjectionMatrix;

varying vec2 v_texcoord;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = modelViewProjectionMatrix * vec4(positionCoords, 0.0, 1.0);
    v_texcoord = textureCoords.xy;
}
```

> **Fragment:**

```
precision highp float;

varying vec2 v_texcoord;

uniform sampler2D s_texture;

void main()
{
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(s_texture, v_texcoord);
}
```

Comment: hey could I perhaps have the ode that you used to pass stuff into the shader?  The texture loading and passing codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

problem resolved,

using glvertexarray to bind the vertex buffer data